# Why can't I check disk on a path mounted NTFS disk

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, chkdsk

### The set-up

I have a laptop running windows 7 with one internal hard drive with 5 partitions

1. NTFS SystemReserved
2. NTFS c:
3. NTFS Shared data
4. Linux Boot
5. Linux Root.

I'm booted into windows and the Linux partitions are not mounted so ignore 4 and 5. I have partition 3 (shared data) mounted as a folder off C drive.

### The Problem

I can't seem to run check disk/error-checking on this partition, to attempt to do so I have opened up Computer Managment->Storage->Disk Managment-> Select Partition-> right click properties -> Tab Tools -> Error Checking -> Check Now.

When I click on the check now button nothing happens, the button appears to be enabled and moves like a button, I get no new window or pop-up, I get no entry in the event log. I don't get my disk checked.

Comment: Even though I managed to get this working (see my answer below) I would be interested in any idea why.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried "chkdsk C:\data" from a console? Have a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/218461, which describes (amongst other things) using chkdsk on a disk mounted as a mount point.

JR

Comment: Yep, works fine from console. still remembered the command from NT4 days but did not think to actually type it in :). Sorry I don't have enough rep for an up vote yet (Stackoverflow user much more then serverfault). Thanks so much.

Comment: Woot! just hit 15 rep, here is your up vote :)

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work as I was typing out the question, I found I could mount this in multiple locations so I mounted my partition as both c:\data and e:\ via the e:\ mount point I could perform check-disk.

Answer (score 1):

If "e:" is considered the "primary" mount point (as disks can only have one drive letter, it probably is) the rest are probably fake to the point that checkdisk complains.

Comment: checkdisk would not know how to exclude c:\data when checking c:, so your answer is correct as e: represents a disk.

Comment: When I was encountering this error the partition was only mounted as c:\data , I mounted as e:\ as well as a work around.

Comment: Just re wording. This drive had no letter at all when I in-counted problem but was mapped to an empty folder(data) on a NTFS partion (c:\\) so the only path that this partition could be accessed from was c:\data. One reason for this is to avoid the 26 device limit of drive letters so I'm pretty sure there is not a hidden drive letter hanging around